# Checkbox obrigatório com javascript para clicar em link

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, menu

Boa noite pessoal!

Estou fazendo um site pra um trabalho da faculdade, e o que quero fazer é o seguinte: Tenho um simples menu em HTML cujas opções são "Visualizar Perfil", "Editar Perfil" e "Remover Perfil". Nesta última, há um checkbox dizendo que o usuário tem certeza do que quer. Para remover o perfil a pessoa deve primeiramente ter selecionado ele (parecido com  aqueles "Li e aceito os termos"). Caso clique em "remover perfil" sem antes ter selecionado o checkbox, deve ser exibida uma mensagem de erro.

**Minha dúvida:** Como construir um código que seja obrigatório o usuário clicar no checkbox antes para remover o perfil e ser direcionado para outra página, e caso ele não faça isso exibir uma mensagem de erro?

Veja o código:

```
       <ul id="menuperfil">
           <li><a href="perfilview.html">Visualizar Perfil</a></li>     
           <li><a href="perfiledit.html">Editar Perfil</a></li>
           <li><a href="perfildelete.html">Remover Perfil</a>
             <form>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remover">Tenho certeza de que desejo remover o perfil.
             </form></li>
       </ul>
```

Com o CSS ele fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E ai galera? Alguma sugestão??

Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Felipe! Por favor use um minuto do seu tempo para fazer o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), e saber melhor como o site funciona! Há mais informações na [Central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help). E veja se [essa resposta lhe ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6796/4816).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="fcnConfirma();">Remover Perfil</a>
<input type="checkbox" id="remover" name="remover">Tenho certeza de que desejo remover o perfil.


<script type="text/javascript">
    function fcnConfirma() {
        if (!document.getElementById('remover').checked) {
            alert("Marque a opção:\nTenho certeza de que desejo remover o perfil.");
            return;
        }else{
            window.open("perfildelete.html","_self")
            // window.open("perfildelete.html","_blank")
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Funcionou!! Muito obrigado! ^^

Comment: @Felipe, se nosso amigo Lelecko resolveu seu problema não esqueça de setar a resposta como [**resolvida**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079)! =D