# Deixando o input em foco após válidação do javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Implementei uma válidação simples para checar se o input corresponde as regras e caso seja negativo o mesmo deve ficar em foco para alteração do dado, mas o foco não está funcionando, ele deixa o próximo ítem em foco e não o que foi setado no javascript, já retirei o required e mesmo assim não funciona segue o código que estou utilizando.

```js
function verificaForm() {
    //var doc = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
    //alert(doc);
    if (document.formulario.txtName.value === "") {
        alert('Campo nome vazio');
        //document.getElementById('txtName').focus();
        var nome = document.getElementById('txtName');
        document.getElementById('txtName').focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" name="formulario" method="post">
   <div class="form-control">
      <label for="txtName">Nome:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName">
   </div>
   <div class="form-control">
      <label for="txtSobrenome">Sobre-nome</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtSobrenome" name="txtSobrenome">
   </div>
   <div class="form-control">
      <label for="txtIdade">Idade</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtIdade" name="txtIdade">
   </div>
   <div class="form-control">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="verificaForm()">Verificar ...</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Aqui tem um boa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6792/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-formul%C3%A1rios-com-javascript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Basta vc colocar type="button" no button do formulário:

```js
function verificaForm() {
    //var doc = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
    //alert(doc);
    if (document.formulario.txtName.value === "") {
        alert('Campo nome vazio');
        //document.getElementById('txtName').focus();
        var nome = document.getElementById('txtName');
        document.getElementById('txtName').focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" name="formulario" method="post">
   <div class="form-control">
      <label for="txtName">Nome:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName">
   </div>
   <div class="form-control">
      <label for="txtSobrenome">Sobre-nome</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtSobrenome" name="txtSobrenome">
   </div>
   <div class="form-control">
      <label for="txtIdade">Idade</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtIdade" name="txtIdade">
   </div>
   <div class="form-control">
      <button  type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="verificaForm()">Verificar ...</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

> Pode também colocar `document.getElementById("txtName").style.background = "#D4D4D4";` para melhor visualizar o campo em foco. Veja

```js
function verificaForm() {
    //var doc = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
    //alert(doc);
    if (document.formulario.txtName.value === "") {
        alert('Campo nome vazio');
        //document.getElementById('txtName').focus();
        var nome = document.getElementById('txtName');
        document.getElementById('txtName').focus();
        document.getElementById("txtName").style.background = "#D4D4D4";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" name="formulario" method="post">
   <div class="form-control">
      <label for="txtName">Nome:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName">
   </div>
   <div class="form-control">
      <label for="txtSobrenome">Sobre-nome</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtSobrenome" name="txtSobrenome">
   </div>
   <div class="form-control">
      <label for="txtIdade">Idade</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtIdade" name="txtIdade">
   </div>
   <div class="form-control">
      <button  type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="verificaForm()">Verificar ...</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: foi um erro meu não especificar o type no botão, obrigado pela validação, no firefox/chrome e IE perfeito mas no safari não funciona e não queria incluir biblioteca queria usar javascript puro mas acho que não funciona, já passou por isto?

Comment: Não funcionou e não entendi a declaração da variável "var nome =", onde uso ela?

Comment: Essa variável "var nome =" está lá no seu código, para que vc ia usá-la não sei.

Answer (score 1):

Eu já tive esse problema em algum navegar específico, e outro funcionava.

Eu resolvi adicionando um `timeout`, e então setando o `focus` no campo, assim:

```
window.setTimeout(function () { 
    document.getElementById('txtName').focus(); 
}, 0);
```

Creio que vá resolver o seu problema também, uma vez que seu código parece estar certo.

Comment: obrigado por compartilhar a informação, creio que deva ser algum problema no navegador safari tanto em iphone quanto em pcs da aple.

Comment: Não funcionou? Faça um teste, coloque `tabindex` nos seus inputs, 0,1,2, etc, na sequencia que os campos deve ser preenchidos e veja se muda o comportamento do navegador.